# Import product CSV to magento using cronjob

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, import-products, magento-cron

I want to update my products csv to Magento 1.9.0 using cronjob.

so someone can please tell me appropriate code script, please.

because I want to set it using the cronjob

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

For how to import product csv from admin side please follow below links

1) https://www.magestore.com/manage-magento-online-store/magento-import-products

2) https://trellis.co/blog/uploading-products-magento-product-excel/

Using cronjob you need to create cronjob see this example

1) https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133200/73787

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244124/10655735

3) https://github.com/cameraki/Magento-Magmi-Via-Cron-Extension/blob/master/app/code/local/Oli/Magmi/Cron.php

Comment: I want appropriate PHP code. because i want to set cron job

Comment: do you want it using cronjob? check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133200/73787

Comment: suppose my products CSV file name is "allproducts.csv" then how can i use in this code for update all products detail

Comment: please check my updated answer I have added some reference examples